# DirectX in Delphi XE6

Tags: delphi, directx, delphi-xe6

I am looking to load multiple DDS files onto a form but not sure on where to start.

I have looked at Asphyre Sphinx 3 and the DX11_JSB headers for Delphi, but im not sure XE6 is the right environment for this.

Very little documentation for XE6 and Direct X.

I can't post any source code, because i don't know where to begin.

What would be the best way to load these DDS files onto my form (kind of like a Map Viewer / Editor where i could zoom in and out, etc)

```
const
  caly_00 = 'E:\Delphi Projects\OpenP\Maps\map_cal_0.dds';
  caly_01 = 'E:\Delphi Projects\OpenP\Maps\map_cal_1.dds';
  caly_02 = 'E:\Delphi Projects\OpenP\Maps\map_cal_2.dds';
  caly_03 = 'E:\Delphi Projects\OpenP\Maps\map_cal_3.dds';
  caly_04 = 'E:\Delphi Projects\OpenP\Maps\map_cal_4.dds';
  caly_05 = 'E:\Delphi Projects\OpenP\Maps\map_cal_5.dds';

procedure TForm2.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  cvs: TDirect2DCanvas;
  iBitmapBrush: ID2D1BitmapBrush;
  iBitmap_Caly_0, iBitmap_Caly_1, iBitmap_Caly_2, iBitmap_Caly_3, iBitmap_Caly_4, iBitmap_Caly_5: ID2D1Bitmap;
  Size0, Size1, Size2, Size3, Size4, Size5: TD2DSizeF;
  i: integer;
begin
  cvs := TDirect2DCanvas.Create(Canvas, ClientRect);
  iBitmap_Caly_0 := GetD2D1Bitmap(cvs.RenderTarget, Caly_00);
  iBitmap_Caly_0.GetSize(Size0);
  iBitmap_Caly_1 := GetD2D1Bitmap(cvs.RenderTarget, Caly_01);
  iBitmap_Caly_1.GetSize(Size1);
  iBitmap_Caly_2 := GetD2D1Bitmap(cvs.RenderTarget, Caly_05);
  iBitmap_Caly_2.GetSize(Size2);
  iBitmap_Caly_3 := GetD2D1Bitmap(cvs.RenderTarget, Caly_04);
  iBitmap_Caly_3.GetSize(Size3);
  iBitmap_Caly_4 := GetD2D1Bitmap(cvs.RenderTarget, Caly_03);
  iBitmap_Caly_4.GetSize(Size4);
  iBitmap_Caly_5 := GetD2D1Bitmap(cvs.RenderTarget, Caly_02);
  iBitmap_Caly_5.GetSize(Size5);

  cvs.BeginDraw;
  cvs.RenderTarget.SetTransform(TD2DMatrix3x2F.Translation(0, 0));
  cvs.RenderTarget.DrawBitmap(iBitmap_Caly_0, nil, 1, D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_LINEAR, nil);
  cvs.RenderTarget.SetTransform(TD2DMatrix3x2F.Translation(Size0.Height, 0));
  cvs.RenderTarget.DrawBitmap(iBitmap_Caly_1, nil, 1, D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_LINEAR, nil);
  cvs.RenderTarget.SetTransform(TD2DMatrix3x2F.Translation(Size1.Height, Size2.Width));
  cvs.RenderTarget.DrawBitmap(iBitmap_Caly_2, nil, 1, D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_LINEAR, nil);
  cvs.RenderTarget.SetTransform(TD2DMatrix3x2F.Translation(0, Size0.Width));
  cvs.RenderTarget.DrawBitmap(iBitmap_Caly_3, nil, 1, D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_LINEAR, nil);
  cvs.EndDraw;
  cvs.Free;
end;
```

So this will load the images properly to the form, but now i want to zoom in and out, and when i hold down left mouse button you can drag to another position on the image map.

Comment: It looks to me as though you are doing a good job of working this all out.

Comment: Yeah thanks, i did a little bit of research into the topic. I have a feeling that Zoom is going to be more difficult. But ill edit this post and show the zoom function was i get it working.

Comment: I don't want to start a new topic, but what is the main difference between `FRenderTarget: ID2D1HwndRenderTarget;` and `Canvas: TDirect2DCanvas;` both render to the form perfectly, but most examples use the first to render.